# how can I change the deployment target to 5.1.1 in XCode5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm working in a project and I need to support iOS 5.1.1 but in the drop menu of "deployment target" I don't have 5.1.1 as option:

[image]

My question for you guys is how can I add the iOS 5.1.1 as deployment target?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where is that screenshot from? When I select my target in Xcode 5 and go to the "iOS Deployment Target" setting, it shows 4.3 through 7.0.

Comment: ... same for me. - Which Xcode version do you have?

Comment: I see now that this problem appears on the General tab.

Comment: @rmaddy: Only if you have "arm64" as one of the build architectures in the build settings. - It's all said in the "possible duplicate".

Comment: @MartinR I deleted that last comment because after I double checked it turns out I do have arm64 listed. But oddly I can still select back to 4.3 for the "iOS Deployment Target" on the "Build Settings" tab.

Comment: @rmaddy: Perhaps because a project can have multiple targets.

Comment: The only thing is 64 bit architecture is only supported from 5.1.1

Comment: I had to edit the actual .pbxproj file - it wouldnt let me type in the version. This is using Xcode 6.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can type it by hand in the box, if you feel like, and even if this is not available as a dropdown option or you can do the same from "Build Settings">"Deployment">"iOS Deployment Target" section.

However, if you have to go below 5.1.1, please make sure that you have **not** used 64 bit architecture $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT) in your "Build Settings">"Architectures">"Architectures" section. Stick to standard ARM 32 bit architecture $(ARCHS_STANDARD) only.

## **update sep, 15:**

(This portion is not directly related to the actual answer)

Starting from Xcode 6, $(ARCHS_STANDARD) includes 64 bit architecture, by default (armv7 arm64). So, if you archive your code with default "Release" configuration with $(ARCHS_STANDARD), it will create a fat binary with both armv7 and arm64 slices it it. Unfortunately, that kind of binary is not supported in iOS prior to 5.1.1.

So if you are still planning your app for iOS less than 5.1.1 you should set your "Release" architecture to armv7 (and may be armv7s also), explicitly. Alternatively, you could create a separate build configuration for armv7(and armv7s) only architecture and archive your code seperately with both of your "Release" and custom configurations. Although, this is never a good idea for App Store deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Just type 5.1.1 into the deployment target or in the build settings search for the deployment target and choose iOS 5.1 from the dropdown.