# Xcode5.1.1 with Deployment target 5.x?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to set deployment target to `5.x in Xcode 5.1.1` but I can see min is 6.0. So I'm trying to select Architecture to `armv7` alone, but I couldn't see that as below.

[image]

And If I try to manually enter 5.0 into deployment target field, I get below error.

[image]

So Is it possible to set 5.x in Xcode 5.1.1? If no, any other way to do this?

**Note:** According to [apple's news](https://developer.apple.com/news/), From May15, we have to take upload on xcode 5.1.1...

Comment: @matt fine. but This is requirement we cann't change it for development problems. If there is no solution for this, I'll go with this solution.

Comment: @matt Ya accept with you..

Answer (score 2):

As @Chitra pointed out, you can type in a value into that field manually. If you type 5.1.1 then both 32bit and 64bit architectures are selected automatically by Xcode and there's no need to fiddle with architectures (add/remove/anything). So your app will use the correct 64bit binaries on capable hardware.

If you select anything lower than 5.1.1 then all your binaries will be compiled in 32bit only.

This was a new Xcode feature in 5.0.1 I believe. Here's the complete guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score -1):

You can directly type a different target (5.0, 5.1, etc) into the text box :)

The only thing to note is you will need to change the architecture to exclude ARM64 if you go below 7.0.

**EDIT**

Build Settings > iOS Deployment Target

Here no need to exclude ARM64.
I checked it

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891693/how-can-i-change-the-deployment-target-to-5-1-1-in-xcode5 check this answer

Comment: @matt check my edited answer hope this is correct I checked and tested. you were right no need to exclude ARM64.